# How to print a rectangle shape thru multiplication signs in python?

Tags: python, shapes

```
long = int(input("longueur : "))
larg = int(input("largeur : "))
for i in range(larg):
    if i == 0 or i == larg - 1:
        for j in range(long):
            print("* ", end="")
        print()
    else:
        for j in range(long):
            if j == 0 or j == long - 1:
                print("* ", end="")
            else:
                print(end="  ")
        print()
```

I was trying to achieve a rectangle shape through symbols .

I started learning Python recently and I'm searching for a faster/cleaner way to do this .

the output requested is:

```
*  *  *  *
*        *
*  *  *  *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop to iterate through each row. If the row is first or last then fill it with `column * '*'`. If the row is the middle one then add an `'*'`, fill with appropriate spaces and finally add an `'*'`.
Here's how you can do it:

```
long = int(input("longueur : "))
larg = int(input("largeur : "))

for i in range(long):
    if (i == 0) or (i == long - 1): # Checking if it is first or last row
        print('* ' * larg) # Printing entire row without gap
    else: # For middle rows
        print('* ' + '  ' *(larg - 2) + '*') # Printing middle rows with gap in between.
```

Output:

```
longueur : 3
largeur : 4
* * * * 
*     * 
* * * * 

longueur : 4
largeur : 7
* * * * * * * 
*           * 
*           * 
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation , originally I haven't thought about multiplying the spaces in the else statement that saved a lot .

Comment: @TonyAbdelsater If the answer helps you then you can accept it by clicking on tick mark. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean and simple approach...

```
length = int(input("length: "))
width = int(input("width: "))

for i in range(length):
    print("*  " * width)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use multiply with your multiplication signs:

```py
rows = 3
columns = 5

print(('* ' * columns + '\n') * rows, end = '')
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

If you want to print a hollow rectangle, it's a little more complicated as you need different rows in the middle. For example:

```py
for r in range(rows):
    if r == 0 or r == rows - 1:
        print('* ' * columns)
    else:
        print('* ' + '  ' * (columns - 2) + '* ')
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
*       *
* * * * *
```

Comment: hey, Thanks for your answer I have corrected the desired output if you can help me again I want it to be empty from the inside

Comment: thank you , that's really helpful { print('* ' + '  ' * (columns - 2) + '* ')} i haven't thought about it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the good old basic **for loop**

```
rows = 3
columns = 3


for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        print('*', end='  ')
    print()
```

will give

```
*  *  *  
*  *  *  
*  *  *
```

as per your updated question for hollow

```
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
        if i == 1 or i == rows or j == 1 or j == columns:
            print("*", end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ", end=" ")
    print()
```

will give

```
* * * 
*   * 
* * *
```

Comment: hey, Thanks for your answer I have corrected the desired output if you can help me again I want it to be empty from the inside